# All my work is gone

Tags: saving

I've made a few things in Blender like Mountains and Trees. After i saved them i wanted to show them my family and everything was gone. There was only the Mesh left (Mountain) and the tree textures were gone. 
Am I doing something wrong?

I saved them as i would save things normally under ''Save as'', if that helps understanding my issue. I searched already but i couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally saved it into another directory? Try to search for file ending in `.blend` on your system.

Comment: I checked but they are all saved as .blend.

Comment: It's unlikely that your changes haven't been saved if you actually used either *Save* or *Save As*. If you've been using *Save As* there is a chance that you've been saving the most recent version to an entirely different directory. Let your OS search through all files on your hard drive that end in `.blend`, this may take while but it will find the misplaced file, if it exists.

Comment: Yes, again. Nothing else but those who i saved. I only have 5 files so there are no more. They are all .blend type. I only saved them at the end after i was done. I did a rendered image save and that i can find. But the work in gerneral is gone.

Comment: I see, so you've got as many files as the number of times you saved the project. Then it's really hard to tell. Have you tried to recover the last session?

Comment: No so i have only 5 different files which have nothing to do with each other. I don't  need to recover it. I don't really care about those 2 files but i would like to solve the problem, so it won't happen again in the future where i might have some important files.

Comment: Can you share your .blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.  It may help us figure out what happened.

Comment: Here you go, but you won't see that much cause only the planes are left. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6914" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6914/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Updated:* See note below on how to find your nodes.

Okay, I think the only problem is that, when you reopen your file, by default it displays in "Solid" mode.  This doesn't show any textures, and it won't show the result of material-based displacement either, which is how you made your plane into a mountain.  That's why you only see two flat planes.

So, after opening your file, click on the "Render" icon:

[image]

or alternatively hit "Z" in the viewport and select "Rendered" from the wheel menu.

In addition, your file contains references to the following external texture files.  If you still have them in place, then everything should look fine.

```
/tmp/textures/av2f1080fa1c4f0e6f74d.png
/tmp/textures/moos.jpg
/tmp/textures/rock_face_texture_by_bactaboy.jpg
/tmp/textures/roughness_texture.jpg
/tmp/textures/sand.jpg
/tmp/textures/sand_text.jpg
/tmp/textures/Seamless mountain rock face texture.jpg
/tmp/textures/Substance0053_5_download600.jpg
/tmp/textures/texture_sky.jpg
```

But, by default, external textures like these are not saved as part of the .blend file, and if something wipes `/tmp/textures`, you'll lose them all.  If that happens, you'll see the plane, mountain, and reflective water shapes, but they'll all be a bright magenta color, like in my screenshot, meaning the texture files are missing.

So, if the files are still there or if you can restore them from where you got them, you may want to save them in the .blend file by selecting `File -> External Data -> Pack All Into .blend` from the menu, or check the box under `File -> External Data -> Automatically Pack Into .blend`.

You can also move the files somewhere more permanent and then use "File -> External Data -> Find Missing Files" to fix the references in Blender.

In a comment, you also asked about finding your node system.  To see the full node system for the ground plane after opening the file:

- In the 3D Viewport, click to select the ground mesh.
- Expand the Shader Editor window on the left a bit.
- In the Shader Editor window, zoom out with the mouse wheel, or use the key sequence <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and <kbd>NumPad Period</kbd> to view the selection.

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: That was very helpful but my nodes are all gone too? Can i get them back as well?

Comment: I think your nodes are all there (e.g., I see your large node system of about 50 nodes for the ground mesh).  You just need to make sure you're looking in the Shader Editor at the right material and get the nodes in the viewport.  I'll add something to the answer.

Comment: Haha yeah, i just found them. I didn't know that i have to select the plane. The camera was selected in default so there were no nodes. Stupid me. Thank you anyways very much.

Comment: But why is everything magenta then? How can i fix that, so my textures are showing again?

Comment: If everything is magenta, that means one or more external files in `/tmp/textures` that I listed above are now missing.  They weren't saved with the .blend file, unfortunately, and you'll need to restore them from wherever you got them.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the solution when in the node area there should be a section in the middle called slot and material. there will be a icon of a ball with two parts of it shaded click that and go through them and the nodes should be there.